# What are the naming rules for \newwrites in TeX? Can \newwrites be created dynamically?

Tags: tex-core, external-files, filesystem-access

I can create a `\newwrite` like this:

```
\newwrite\filehandle
\immediate\openout\filehandle=\jobname-semantically_useful_suffix.txt
\immediate\closeout\filehandle
```

Let's say I have languages stored in a macro: da, de, en, ...
Loop each language and store it as `\langcode`

**I need a unique file handle for each language.** I would like to have something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% xelatex
\usepackage{tikz}% foreach
\usepackage{morewrites}% unnecessary for this example, but useful in practice to exceed 16-write limit in TeX

\def\writelangouts{%
  \foreach \langcode in {da,de,en} {% from tikz package
    \newwrite\filehandle-\langcode
    \immediate\openout\filehandle-\langcode=\jobname-semantically_useful_suffix_\langcode.txt
    \immediate\closeout\filehandle-\langcode
  }%
}%
\AtEndDocument{\writelangouts}

\begin{document}
\jobname
\end{document}% \writelangouts executed here
```

I would like to have a list of naming conventions for the **file handle macros** (`\newwrite`) and **file names** (`\openout=filename`).

1. I assume you cannot use `\csname...\endcsname` for file handle macros.
2. I assume file names are dependent upon the local filesystem's naming conventions.

---

**Notes:**
In reality I am defining sectioning commands (headings) to write their numbers to a macro as to create a toc-like structure for each language. Then I compare each language's output with the Unix utility `diff` to look for differences. This is particularly useful for cross checking translations.

e.g.

```
§ 1
  § 1.1
    § 1.1.1
    § 1.1.2
  § 1.2
§ 2
  § 2.1
  § 2.2
```

Comment: The usual problem of `\foreach` doing its job in a group can be of a hindrance.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Oh really? I did not know you could do that. What do you mean, "given that `\filehandle` is defined"?  I thought `\newwrite` is defining it.

Comment: @macmadness86: No, you must construct the sequence name with `\csname filehandle-\langcode\endcsname` then

Comment: are you using hyperref? I think there is an easy way.

Comment: @touhami At this point, you could provide an addendum with an alternative approach, but the question has been answered definitively. My goal was to learn the limits of `\newwrite`.

Comment: i hope you are achieving your goal :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\newwrite\foo` assigns the symbolic name to be equal to a write file register, so anything that is possible with `\csname ...\endcsname` is also possible with `\newwrite` or `\newread`, as well as with `\openout`,`\openin`, `\closein`, `\closeout`.

`\newwrite` itself is no `TeX` primitive but assigns the next free output stream number to a macro name via a `\chardef`, the same is true for `\newread` -- both stream directions are independent of each other!

In this sense, a file handle is nothing more than a macro expanding to a number, this way `\immediate\write6` etc. would be possible too. (or think of writing to the shell with `\immediate\write18` (given that shell-escape is enabled)).

If there's another macro inside the `\csname...\endcsname` statement, use an `\expandafter`.

The point is now: How feasible is this approach? It can be quite tedious to repeat the `\csname ... \endcsname` usage all the while!

Here is a similar code from the `\@starttoc` command in `latex.ltx`:

```
\def\@starttoc#1{%
  \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \@input{\jobname.#1}%
    \if@filesw
      \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
      \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
    \fi
    \@nobreakfalse
  \endgroup}
```

It can be seen that the file handle of the toc - file is generated on the fly over and over again (for each `\@starttoc` - call)

Some points to consider:

- My solution is only correct if opening, writing and closing is within the `\foreach` cycle, since this establishes a group, so the filename handle macro name isn't available outside of the `\foreach` - cycle. However, this procedure is not recommended.
- Is it really necessary to use a new handle for each file? No, not really, since apparently the file handle is generated, the file opened etc. and the 'active' file is determined by the `\foreach` loop variable `\langcode`, so it's not easily possible to write to more than one file(handle) at the 'same' time.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% xelatex
\usepackage{tikz}% foreach
\usepackage{morewrites}% unnecessary for this example, but useful in practice to exceed 16-write limit in TeX


\def\writelangouts{%
  \foreach \langcode in {da,de,en} {% from tikz package
    \expandafter\newwrite\csname filehandle-\langcode\endcsname
    \immediate\openout\csname filehandle-\langcode\endcsname=\jobname-semantically_useful_suffix_\langcode.txt
    \immediate\closeout\csname filehandle-\langcode\endcsname
  }%
}%

    \def\otherwritelangouts{%
  \foreach \langcode in {da,de,en} {% from tikz package
    \def\fhandle{\csname filehandle-\langcode\endcsname}
    \newwrite\fhandle%
    \immediate\openout\fhandle=\jobname-semantically_useful_suffix_\langcode.txt
    \immediate\closeout\fhandle
  }%
}%


\AtEndDocument{\writelangouts}

\begin{document}
\jobname
\end{document}
```

Assuming the file above is called `fhandle.tex`, the `.log` - file shows that following file handles are generated (at the end of the document, since `\writelangouts` is used in `\AtEndDocument`)

```
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box53
\filehandle-da=\write5
\openout4 = `fhandle-semantically_useful_suffix_da.txt'.

\filehandle-de=\write6
\openout4 = `fhandle-semantically_useful_suffix_de.txt'.

\filehandle-en=\write7
\openout4 = `fhandle-semantically_useful_suffix_en.txt'.
```

Comment: It doesn't generally work because of the grouping, unless all the tasks related to writing, from opening up to closing, is performed in the `\foreach` cycle.

Comment: Of course I assumed the writing in the `\foreach` cycle -- otherwise the closing right after opening would be pretty useless. I know about the `\foreach` issues, that's why I rarely use it. Using the whole process of opening, writing and closing in a cycle, one file handle would be enough of course.

Answer (score 5):

If your task is to open a file, write on it and close it all in the same cycle of the `\foreach` loop, you need just one file handle.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}% foreach

\newwrite\langouts
\newcommand\writelangouts{%
  \foreach \langcode in {da,de,en} {% from tikz package
    \immediate\openout\langouts=\jobname-\langcode.txt
    \immediate\write\langouts{This is \langcode}
    \immediate\closeout\langouts
  }%
} 
\AtEndDocument{\writelangouts}

\begin{document}
\jobname
\end{document}
```

The contents of the written files

#### `test-da.txt`

```
This is da
```

#### `test-de.txt`

```
This is de
```

#### `test-en.txt`

```
This is en
```

Comment: Hey that's better programming. I did not know you could use one out macro for multiple files. It seems unusual to have a macro handle for multiple files. Perhaps I do not understand  `\newwrite\langouts` completely.

Comment: @macmadness86 So long as you close the previous file before opening a new one, you just need one handle.